# init.d script cannot access alsa audio

Tags: alsa, init-script, init.d

I've written a simple init.d script to start an [hardware monitor script](http://eadmaster.altervista.org/pub/prj/cliapps/hwleds.py).
It works fine except it cannot access the alsa audio service:

```
#! /bin/sh

SCRIPT_PATH="/d/SharedPrograms/hwleds.py"

case $1 in
    start)
        say "starting service hwleds..."
        python $SCRIPT_PATH &
        exit $?
        ;;
    stop)
        pkill -f "python $SCRIPT_PATH"
        exit $?
        ;;
    restart)
        $0 stop
        sleep 1
        $0 start
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac

exit 1
```

The error i get from both the `say` command and the python script is:

```
audio_open_alsa: failed to open audio device default. Operation not permitted
```

edit: The python script can access alsa if it is started normally by the root user via an interactive shell, it only fails if it is started as a service during boot or via `service hwleds start`.

My actual `/root/.asoundrc`:

```
defaults.pcm.card 0
defaults.pcm.device 3

ctl.equal {
  type equal;
}

pcm.plugequal {
  type equal;
  # Modify the line below if you don't
  # want to use sound card 0.
  slave.pcm "plughw:0,3";
  # or if you want to use with multiple applications output to dmix
  # slave.pcm "plug:dmix"
}

#pcm.equal {
  # Or if you want the equalizer to be your
  # default soundcard uncomment the following
  # line and comment the above line.
 pcm.!default {
  type plug;
  slave.pcm plugequal;
}
```

Comment: As which user executes this script? Root? Which is the default device (`aplay -L` and check `/etc/asound.conf` and `~/.asoundrc` for this user, e.g. root)? Maybe a default device doesn't exist for root on your system?

Comment: Check the permissions on the device nodes in `/dev/snd/`.

Comment: @dirkt: the script is executed as root (checked with `whoami`). Also i'm quite sure root can access the default alsa device because this is puppy linux.

Comment: The point is not *accessing* the `default` device. ALSA has user-specific sound configuration, so even if normal users do have a `default` device defined (which is just an alias for some other device), that doesn't mean root does. So log in as root, and try `aplay -D default some_wav_file`. Then do `aplay -L` etc.

Comment: Also, I'd be kind of reluctant to run a python script as root, given you could run it as a less privileged user instead who is member in a group that has access to leds and sound device nodes.

Comment: @dirkt: `aplay -D default stereo_test.wav` works fine as root. I've also added root to the audio group but nothing changes.

Comment: Interestingly, launching the python script as a regular/non-root user as dirkt suggested works! Maybe this is a security feature of alsa?

Comment: If it was a security feature of ALSA, you wouldn't be able to use `aplay`. I suspect python plays a role, but that's hard to debug without delving into the ALSA lib for python. Can you write up the "launch as non-root user" as answer, including how to do it, so the next person with a similar problem gets help?

Comment: i've just tested the same code on another Jessie setup, and here the service works fine, but it is started via `systemd`... i need to investigate this more. btw I don't think the problem is related to python since the same error is thrown by the `say` command (which is not a python script).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on volumio. Solved by removing `.alsaequal.bin` from `/var/lib/mpd/`